# How to handle a series of paired files

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

In a folder `collection`, I have following files:

```
fberry.txt   lberry.txt
fgag.txt     lgag.txt
fred.txt     lred.txt
ftea.txt     ltea.txt
fluck.txt    lluck.txt
```

We can find that these files can be divided into two types: one begins with `f`, and the other begins with `l`. And every two files share a same name (except the first letter), for example: In `fberry.txt` and `lberry.txt`, `berry.txt` is the same. In these two paired files, the first column of each file is the same, I want to merge these two files (the first two columns of `lberry.txt` and the third column of `fberry.txt`) based on the same column.

I use following code:

```
cd ~/collection
awk 'NR==FNR {h[$1]=$3; next} {print $1,$2,h[$1]}' fberry.txt lberry.txt > tberry.txt
```

It can produce the result I want, but I don't know how to handle all these paired files together, otherwise, I need to write 5 codes like this, and if there are 100+ files, it will be a disaster.

My expected result is to get 5 new files: `tberry.txt`,`tgag.txt`,`tred.txt`,`ttea.txt` and `tluck.txt`.Thanks.

Comment: *"how to handle all these paired files together"* meaning what, exactly? are you asking how to loop over pairs of files an run the awk command on each pair?

Comment: @don_crissti  Thank you so much! `${file:1}` is exactly what I want. It can get the string after the first character. I checked this and find that the syntax is `${string: index: length}`. Thanks again! I will do the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for file in f*.txt
do name=${file:1}
awk 'NR==FNR {h[$1]=$3; next} {print $1,$2,h[$1]}' "$file" "l$name" > "t$name"
done
```

Thanks to @don_crissti. 
Here, `${file:1}` can extract the characters after the first character. With this, I can easily get the common part of paired filenames. The syntax of `${file:1}` is `${string: index: length}`.